# MS Access VBA change column to display from Value List to number

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following table in MS Access:

- app_id = PK, auto increment
- app = Number, display as Value List(No, YES)

My table sample data:

```
tblapp
app_id  app
1        NO
2        No
3        YES
```

I would like to convert column `app` to show number

`no = 1` and `yes = 2`

using vba

Convert desire table:

```
tblapp
app_id  app
1        1
2        1
3        2
```

One solution is to create a new column, copy data. Then delete old column and rename new to old name.

Any other solution?

Comment: That's a good solution. Go ahead.

Comment: @Gustav Thank you Gustav. I will go this solution. I believe in your messages.

Comment: @Gustav Can i rename column with `ALTER TABLE Statement`?

Comment: Not that I know of - [ALTER TABLE statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/alter-table-statement-microsoft-access-sqlWT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361). So, copy to a temp field, remove the old, recreate it with the correct data type, copy data from the temp field, remove temp field.

Comment: @Gustav I create the following answer. It is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on `Gustav` comment i made the following solution.

The VBA code:

```
Private Sub btn_Click()
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql As String
Set dbs = CurrentDb

' Add temp column.
dbs.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblapp ADD COLUMN temp_app NUMBER;"

' Add-update data to temp column.
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT app_id, IIF(app="NO", 1, 2) AS temp_app FROM tblapp;", dbOpenDynaset)
With rst
    Do Until .EOF
            sql = "UPDATE [tblapp] SET [temp_app] = '" & rst!temp_app & "' WHERE [app_id] = " & rst!app_id & " ;"
            dbs.Execute (sql)
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

' Delete app column(old).
dbs.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblapp DROP app;"

' Add new app column.
dbs.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblapp ADD COLUMN app NUMBER;"

' Copy data from temp to app column.
dbs.Execute "UPDATE tblapp Set app = temp_app;"

' Delete temp column.
dbs.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblapp DROP temp_app;"

rst.Close
dbs.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the table is extremely big, you may find it more speed efficient to create a brand new table according to the new columns you want, where you simply transfer the data across with the appropriate transformations. You could do this most likely all with saved queries (thus avoiding the need for VBA), or alternatively, run the SQL for the queries from VBA.

The reason why it may be more efficient, is because the table data is probably stored contiguously on disk, such that adding a new column doesn't simply add the new data to the end of the contiguous region, but goes about adding a new space every n bytes for each row's value for the new column. This could result in a great deal of re-organisation work with respect to the space on disk. If instead you followed the above alternative method, it may take up more space temporarily (because you have to create a second table), but overall could be quite a bit faster.